# Polchinski, (0,0) picture vertex operator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, supersymmetry, grassmann-numbers

I am currently working through chapter 12 of Polchinski and am confused as to how the equation $(12.3.39)$ for the (0,0) picture vertex operator arises. From the text:

> The state–operator mapping in chapter 10 gave the NS–NS vertex
>   operators as $$\delta(\gamma)\delta(\tilde\gamma) =
>  e^{-\phi-\tilde\phi} $$(12.3.38) times a $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$
>   superconformal tensor. These are the analog of the ﬁxed bosonic vertex
>   operators. We have seen that the superconformal tensors are the lowest
>   components of superﬁelds, which do indeed correspond to the value of
>   the superfield when $\theta$ and $\overline \theta$ are ﬁxed at 0.
>   Calling this tensor $\mathcal{O}$, eq. (12.3.15) gives the vertex
>   operator integrated over $\theta$ and $\overline\theta$ as $$ \mathcal{V}^{0,0}=G_{-1/2}\tilde G_{-1/2}\cdot \mathcal{O} \tag{12.3.39}$$This operator appears without the
>   $\delta(\gamma)\delta(\tilde\gamma)$.

Here the index $(0,0)$ denotes the picture, and $\mathcal{O}$ is part of the superfield

$$ \phi=\mathcal{O}(z) + \theta\Psi(z)$$ The equations (12.3.15) are

\begin{align} &G_{-1/2}\cdot \mathcal{O} = \Psi, \quad G_r \cdot \mathcal{O}=0,r \geq\frac{1}{2} \\& G_{-1/2}\cdot\Psi = \partial \mathcal{O}, \quad G_{1/2}\cdot \Psi = 2h\mathcal{O}, \quad G_r \cdot\Psi=0, \, r\geq\frac{3}{2}
\end{align} $\mathcal{O}$ is a tensor of weight $h$, and $\Psi$ is a tensor of weight $h+\frac{1}{2}$. I do not see how these equations give the vertex operator integrated over the anticommuting variables. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. $\mathcal{V}^{0}$ is the vertex operator integrated over $\theta$. Integrating $\phi$ over $\theta$ gives us $\Psi$, and we can use equations (12.3.15) to rewrite $\Psi$ as $G_{-1/2}\cdot \mathcal{O}$.

In order to get the $\tilde G_{-1/2}$ factor for the $\mathcal{V}^{0,0}$ operator we must expand $\phi$ further,

$$ \phi = \mathcal{O} +\theta\Psi + \overline \theta \overline \Psi+\theta \overline \theta W$$ There is then an additional term in the equation for $\delta\Psi$, namely $\overline\eta W$, which by the Ward identity gives the relation $\tilde G_{-1/2}\Psi=W$. So $\mathcal{V}^{0,0}=G_{-1/2} \tilde G_{-1/2}\cdot \mathcal{O}=W$, which is indeed the only term from $\phi$ that survives the integration over $d^2 \theta$.